# jquery - Check to see if any radio button selected had a value greater than 4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few questions in a form field. The answers are radio buttons and each has a unique value. I am adding up the values and passing them to a hidden field.

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(){
    if($( "fieldset:visible input:radio").hasClass( "selected" )){

        $( ".selected").each(function(){
            points = points+parseFloat($(this).attr("answer"));
        });

        $("#total_points").val(points);

        $( "#quiz_form" ).submit();

    }
});
```

However I want to check if any of the values are over 3 and I am not sure how to test for it. I tried adding

```
$( ".selected").each.attr("answer") >= 3)
```

but cant get anything to work.

If there is a value over 3 I want to set a hidden field to 1 on submission.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the items based on the value of the attribute `answer`, if that's where you keep it, then make sure that there's at least one result:

```
var hasOverThree =$(".selected").filter(function(){ 
    return +$(this).attr('answer') >=3;
}).length > 0;
```

Then setting the value of a hidden field if that's true (let's say the id of the field is `hiddenField`):

```
if(hasOverThree)}{
   $('#hiddenField').val(1);
}
```

Edited: OP wants to set hidden field on submit, so you could just create the variable `hasOverThree` right within the submit:

```
$( "#quiz_form" ).submit(function(){
    if(hasOverThree)}{
       $('#hiddenField').val(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I only want to set the value of the hidden field when they submit the form. Im not sure  where to add the script to do this.

Comment: Once I added the function to the submit the form would not submit. I have a dev server here: http://fdn.thelabelcreative.com/survey

Answer (score 0):

```
if($( 'fieldset:visible input[type="radio"]:selected').val() >= 3){
    $('#hiddenField').val(1);
}
```

is this what youre looking for?

are you trying to count radio buttons and add some kind of result?  if thats the case you could use "each" in the above example

Comment: Close. I want to test if any of the questions had an answer with a value over 3. Not just the current one. The 'fieldset:visible' is there to make sure all the answers were filled out. I also dont want to set the hidden field until the form is submitted.